# Change value of dropdowns in javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have a form where there are 16 individual elements the user must fill. In the dropdown for these elements are the values 0-16. The initial value of all these elements is zero.

The user may choose each value from 1 to 16 for each element, but they may only choose each
element once. As they choose each value, I am changing the value of the dropdowns of all the elements to eliminate the chosen values. In the end, the only values left in each dropdown are 0 and the value the user chose for that dropdown. It also puts back the values if the user changes a value back to zero.

The way I have it set up works fine in Chrome and FireFox, but fails in IE. The problem is the `opts.options` is an undefined error. Somehow it works in all browsers but IE. I think I need to pass the element as an object to the method that populates the dropdowns.

Here is how the methods are called in the PHP/HTML, it also calls the
methods on load to initialize the dropdowns:

```
echo "<TD bgcolor=$color width=15><SELECT name='$pts' onChange='populatePoints(this)' </SELECT></TD>n";
```

Here is the relevant JS:

```
   function populatePoints(x){

 setOptions (document.form1.G1_Points)

 setOptions (document.form1.G2_Points)

 setOptions (document.form1.G3_Points)

 setOptions (document.form1.G4_Points)

 setOptions (document.form1.G5_Points)

 setOptions (document.form1.G6_Points)

 setOptions (document.form1.G7_Points)

 setOptions (document.form1.G8_Points)

 setOptions (document.form1.G9_Points)

 setOptions (document.form1.G10_Points)

 setOptions (document.form1.G11_Points)

 setOptions (document.form1.G12_Points)

 setOptions (document.form1.G13_Points)

 setOptions (document.form1.G14_Points)

 setOptions (document.form1.G15_Points)

 setOptions (document.form1.G16_Points)


 }

 function setOptions (opts){

 pointValue = opts.value

 opts.options.length = 0

 var x = 0

 opts.options[x] = new Option(0)

 x++

 for (i=1;i<17;i++) {

 if (document.form1.G1_Points.value != i &&

 document.form1.G2_Points.value != i &&

 document.form1.G3_Points.value != i &&

 document.form1.G4_Points.value != i &&

 document.form1.G5_Points.value != i &&

 document.form1.G6_Points.value != i &&

 document.form1.G7_Points.value != i &&

 document.form1.G8_Points.value != i &&

 document.form1.G9_Points.value != i &&

 document.form1.G10_Points.value != i &&

 document.form1.G11_Points.value != i &&

 document.form1.G12_Points.value != i &&

 document.form1.G13_Points.value != i &&

 document.form1.G14_Points.value != i &&

 document.form1.G16_Points.value != i &&

 document.form1.G15_Points.value != i){

 opts.options[x] = new Option(i)

 x++}}

 opts.value = pointValue

 }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It seems like busy work...

Comment: You can access your forms via `document.['form'+form_number]['G'+i+'_Points'].value` instead of doing all that copy-paste

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't like clearing options this way: `opts.options.length = 0`

Clear out your options like this in IE:

```
for (i=options.length-1; i>=0; i--)   {
      select.removeChild(options[i]);   
}
```

or do this (fastest way to clear):

```
select.innerHTML = "";
```